golang regex excludes head symbols
There is some strings like:
.texta texti(
 .textb textj(
 textc textk(

Go playground:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    text := ".texta texta(, .textb textb(, textc textc("
    pattern := `[^.,]\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)

    for _, match := range matches {
        if len(match) > 1 {
            fmt.Println(match[1])
        }
    }
}


Why the result has "exta", "extb"?
The target is to get "textc", excludes words started with "." or ","."
If the pattern is \s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(, the result is "texta", "textb" and "textc"

You forgot to post your code

The problem is that your regex is not "anchored" to any specific position while you expect \w+ to start matching at the beginning of a word. The [^,.] matches any character other than . and , and it can match a word character.  So, you need to make sure the negated character class does not match  word character, and you may want to also allow a match at the start of the string, you will need to add an alternative.
You can use
pattern := `(?:[^.,\w]|^)\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(`

where (?:[^.,\w]|^) matches either a char other the ., , or word char, or a position at the start of the string.
See the Go playground demo.
